# Expo build:ios Something went wrong when trying to ensure App ID exists on Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to run `build:ios` on expo, when I select the

> ? Will you provide your own Apple Push Notifications service key? Let
>   Expo handle the process

It throws an error tells me I don't have access on membership resource. I'm not the owner of the team. I'm just a developer with an App manager Role.

> × Something went wrong when trying to ensure App ID exists on Apple
>   Developer Portal! Reason: Unexpected response, raw:
>   {"responseId":"","resultCode":1200,"resultString":"Access Unavailable","userString":"You currently don't have access to this
>   membership resource. Contact your team's Account Holder, Account holder,
>   or an
>   Admin.","creationTimestamp":"2019-09-27T07:56:56Z","protocolVersion":"QH65B2","userLocale":"en_US","requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/identifiers/listAppIds.action","httpCode":200}

Can I just skip this question? or there's alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give the user additional resources. Namely `Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`, since you are trying to list identifiers.